# Permission denied error on filewrite function

Tags: python, python-3.x, permission-denied

I wrote some code to parse XML and output the parsed information to two files.  I then read those files and submit to a site with requests POST module. When I try to append the response from said POST to a file, I've been receiving PermissionError, [Errno 13] Permission Denied error (from line 112, submittoSite function in the code posted below).

The section it's happening is thus:

```
with open(xmfp + "nsresponse.csv", "a") as responsefile:
    responsefile.write(r.text + ", %d" % r.status_code + "\n")
```

Why is the file giving me a permission denied error, when I'm only writing it directly in line with the function?  I write to the files that I'm parsing the XML out to fine, and this doesn't happen.  It's at the end of a function.  It's not trying to do more than one at a time, like threading, and doesn't a 'with' statement close the file once it's done?

Before saying something like 'write it to an array and then write it all to a file at once', I'm specifically not doing that because I'm doing 250k'ish POST calls (one of the reasons I wanted to multithread it) and I'm trying to keep RAM down.

[Here's the full code (slightly edited due to work things)](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/k0RiWfJW)

*NOTE: If you've read the code and are wondering about the threading stuff, I realize the multithreading stuff in there is extraneous now, but I'm still hoping that at some point I'll figure out how to get that to run without them interfering with each other, even if I have to rewrite stuff, so I'm just leaving it in there while I work on this.*

Comment: what is `r.text` and `r.status_code`?

Comment: They're the return values from the requests POST command.  it's r = requests.post(NSAddrx, data=jsondata, headers=NSHeaders) r.text is the return from the site (I'm returning response data about whether an item was updated or created), and r.statuscode is 200 (or 401, or whatever, but should be 200 unless timeout or something, which I've accounted for).

Comment: I didn't know you had responded, as the `@T.Woody` was not added in your message. Have you tried running your program and just doing a `write('bar')`?

Comment: @T.Woody Instead of writing the values? I have not.  I added an extra line of  `while responsefile.closed == False: responsefile.close()` after the 'with' statement to open it, but it still came up with the error.  It stopped on the with open line and gave me the permission denied error.

Comment: Test writing just bar without modifying anything else, please :)

Comment: @T.Woody  So it's run without crashing when I wrote just 'bar' instead of the r.text and statuscode.  I didn't even write /n for it.  I wouldn't think it would be the r.text or the status code, since if the value wasn't right, it wouldn't give me a permission error, but rather a fault in converting a number or text or something, right?

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure, without looking more closely at the code in full and `r.text` / `r.status_code`. My next suggestion would to run your program with just printing `a = (r.text + ", %d" % r.status_code + "\n")` and `print(a)`. Do not write it to file yet. a might be unicode, binary, or something else which is causing an issue when writing to a text file. There are a lot of possibilities on what is going wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178892/discussion-between-d-w-and-t-woody).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the code into several blocks to see where the error is coming from.
Let your code snippet that you originally provided look like this instead for testing the error:

```
with open(xmfp + "nsresponse.csv", "a") as responsefile:
    foo = r.text + ", %d" % r.status_code + "\n"
    print(foo)
    responsefile.write("bar")
```

Furthermore, it appears after looking at the full code, the issue appears to be somewhere else. Test case:

```
import requests
import json
w = 'http://google.com'
r = requests.post(w)
foo = r.text
bar = r.status_code
baz = foo + ", %d" % bar + "\n"

with open('out.temp', 'a') as f:
 f.write(baz)
```

Comment: Although this didn't actually fix the issue, it did help me FIND and solve the issue.  The issue was actually that the file was writing to a directory where OneDrive was constantly trying to back it up; due to the nature of delays in the time between the POST response and then writing the next one, OneDrive would try to then back up the file, causing it to be inaccessible just long enough to cause an error.

Comment: @DW I was just going to get back to you and let you know I did a simple test with `http://google.com`, and everything worked fine. Sorry for leading you down the wrong path for the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not allow opening of a file with write access if it is already opened by another thread or process with write access, so if two of your threads are trying to write to the file at the same time, one of them will get permission denied.

You should instead place a lock before trying to open the file with write permission:

```
from threading import Lock
def worker(lock):
    with lock:
        with open(xmfp + "nsresponse.csv", "a") as responsefile:
            responsefile.write(r.text + ", %d" % r.status_code + "\n")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = threading.Lock()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(worker, lock)
```

Comment: Yeah, if I was using the threading, but it's not; the threading points are commented out: it's calling the submit function directly, and then writing the file, and then moving to the next piece.  It happens on the last section: the 230 / 235 line(s).

Comment: @blhsing OP did say his program is running without threads now. The post should probably be `edited` to ask the question without the large dialogue...